# Do I need a local array when using Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I'm currently writing my first iOS app and I'm trying to implement Core Data. Users create food recipes and I want them saved to persistent storage.

Currently, without Core Data, I'm putting the recipes into an array from a singleton.

When I implement Core Data can I do away with this and fetch straight from the data model every time I need to update my `UITableView`? In the `viewDidLoad` method, create an array from the current data in Core Data every time a user navigates to it?

Comment: @dasdom not if done properly. I've had a core data DB with over 1 million records (plus relationships etc...) and had no performance issues.

Comment: @dasdom no worries :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

You should look at the class `NSFetchedResultsController` it is designed to do this.

There is a great [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) which covers everything including things like automatically updating the table when the core data model changes etc...